# Symmetry generating commutator in Witten's treatment of WZW model

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, lie-algebra, affine-lie-algebra, wess-zumino-witten

In ['Non-abelian Bosonization in Two Dimensions'](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1103940923), Witten writes down the commutation relations between currents and fields of the WZW model in equation (33):

\begin{equation}
\bigg[\frac{1}{2\pi}\bigg(\frac{dg}{d\sigma}g^{-1}(x)\bigg)^{ij},g^k_l(y)\bigg]=-i\delta(x-y)(\delta^{jk}g^i_l(y)-\delta^{ik}g^j_l(y)),
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\bigg[\frac{1}{2\pi}\bigg(g^{-1}\frac{dg}{d\sigma}(x)\bigg)^{ij},g^k_l(y)\bigg]=-i\delta(x-y)(\delta^{jl}g^k_i(y)-\delta^{il}g^k_j(y)).
\end{equation}

He explains that these follow since $\int dx \frac{dg}{d\sigma}g^{-1}$ and $\int dx g^{-1}\frac{dg}{d\tau}$ generate the chiral $O(N) \times O(N)$ symmetry, implying that these equations hold up to total
derivatives that vanish after integrating over $x$.

He then says that there can be no such terms via locality and dimensional analysis, since $g$ is dimensionless. How does one show this?

I cannot seem to show that, e.g., a term of the form
$$
\partial_x(g(x)^{ij}g(y)^{k}_l)
$$
does not violate locality or dimensional analysis.

Comment: Doesn't it have the wrong dimension due to the derivative though?

Comment: I’m not sure about this, because there is a derivative on the LHS of each of the commutators as well. Perhaps the delta function is interpreted as having dimensions of inverse length?

Comment: It is, yes, by $\int \delta(x) dx=1$. (That is, most of the time. I assume Witten uses usual delta conventions.)

Comment: @alexarvanitakis Just out of curiosity, what do you mean by "most of the time" $\int \delta(x) dx =1$?

Comment: On a circle of length $\ell$ you could have $\int \delta(x) dx=\ell$, leading to a dimensionless delta. You can also put dimensionful factors elsewhere if you have a metric available --- this delta is a bilocal tensor density, but you could also have one that's an honest tensor, etc.